# Does the ThreadPoolExecutor Apply the Template Pattern?

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor, template-method-pattern

There are 2 *hook methods* in the [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).

This *technique* makes me think of the *template method* pattern, where there are *hook methods* in the `abstract` class. However, the *hook methods* in the *abstract* class of *template method* do differ from that of `ThreadPoolExecutor` in that:

- `ThreadPoolExecutor` class is *concrete*, whereas the class defining the *hook methods* in the *template method* pattern is `abstract`
- *hook methods*, such as `beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r)` and `afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t)`, in `ThreadPoolExecutor` are *concrete* with empty *method body*, whereas *hook methods* in `abstract` class of *template method* pattern are `abstract` albeit the fact that both *hook methods* are `protected` indicating that they should be `overridden` in their *subclasses*

So my **QUESTIONS** are:

- **does the `ThreadPoolExecutor` belong to *template method* pattern** at all?
- **Is the *hook method* per se. an independent *technique* from the *template method* pattern**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would say **yes**, because the ThreadPoolExecutor pre-defines a set of commands that cannot be altered when subclassing as it's marked as `final`. See `#runWorker`. 
This is the template: First `beforeExecute`, second `task.run`, third `afterExecute`.

```
final void runWorker(Worker w) {
  // ... snip
     beforeExecute(wt, task);
     try {
           task.run();
     } 
     ...
     } finally {
        afterExecute(task, thrown);
     }

   // ... snip
}
```

It leaves some parts of the implementation to the subclass, `beforeExecute`, `afterExecute`.

But yes, I'm aware there can be discussion as in this case the class only has hooks (not marked as abstract so permitted but not a requirement) to control subclasses.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your opinion :) so seems that the *hook methods* in *object-oriented programming language* cannot exist independently from *template method*, isn't it so?

Comment: When you think of it logically, it would make little sense to create a class that has hooks without a final template method, yes.

Comment: thanks :) after reading the gof23 again carefully, i found there mentioned the hook operations, which is the default method and can be overridden. So based on this I agree with your answer